# MySQL - Count only if the last associated_statut = 2

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Alright, I have those columns on MySQL :

```
id
id_conv
associated_statut
```

The **associated_statut** is a number between `1` and `7`.

What I want to do is to count only the `id_conv` if the **LAST** associated_statut for this `id_conv` is `2` for example.

Example :

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  id   |   id_conv   |   associated_statut   |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1    |      15     |          1            |
|  2    |      15     |          2            |
|  3    |      15     |          2            |
|  4    |      15     |          4            |
|  5    |      15     |          2            |
|  6    |      15     |          3            |
```

The `id_conv` would NOT be counted if I want the `associated_statut` = 2, because the last associated_statut for this `id_conv` is `3`.

I already tried this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_conv) FROM MyTable WHERE associated_statut = 2
```

But this doesn't returns what I want.

Is there a way to do this in SQL ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post. It's MySQL.

Comment: ?You want to say about last insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this will work for you:

```
SELECT count(t1.id) FROM mytable t1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT id_conv, MAX(id) id FROM foo GROUP BY id_conv) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id 
    WHERE t1.associated_statut = 2
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE associated_statut = 2     is exactly the same thing :(

Comment: I have edited the query. It should group by id_conv instead of id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(sub1.id_conv) FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT id, FIRST(associated_statut ORDER BY id DESC)
group by id_conv
recent FROM MyTable
) sub1 ON sub1.id = MyTable.id
WHERE sub1.recent_associated_statut = 2
```

Comment: partiton functions are not availaible in mysql

Answer (score 0):

We can do same thing without sub query. It will take less time when you have more data.

```
SELECT count(t1.id) FROM 
mytable t1
  LEFT JOIN 
mytable t2
    ON t1.id_conv = t2.id_conv 
    AND t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
AND t1.associated_statut = 2;
```